# Android - Share file from sd using bluetooth

Tags: android, file, bluetooth, send

Im trying to send a file from my `SD` using `Bluetooth`. I'm using Share intent, I wanna send a file from my SD (.`mp3`). ok when I open the share menu, I can send file to `email, dropbox, whatsapp`, but if I select Bluetooth, My device shows a message "`File null was not sent to ...`"

My steps are:
1. Create SEND intent.
2. Copy my file from res/raw to SD
3. Add my file to putExtra
4. Delete the file (is temporal file)

The code:

```
Intent shareIntent=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
        //Copiamos archivo a compartir en la sd
        String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String fileName = sonidoActual+"-temp.mp3";

        File newSoundFile = new File(baseDir, fileName);

        try {
            byte[] readData = new byte[1024*500];
            InputStream fis = getResources().openRawResource(contexto.getResources().getIdentifier(sonidoActual,"raw", contexto.getPackageName()));
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newSoundFile);
            int i = fis.read(readData);

            while (i != -1) {
                fos.write(readData, 0, i);
                i = fis.read(readData);
            }

            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException io) {
        }

        ////
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse(newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath())/*Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/"+fileName)*//*Uri.parse("android.resource://com.genaut.instantbuttonsfreak/raw/"+texto)*/);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,getString(R.string.share)));
        //
        newSoundFile.delete();
```

Anybody can help me with this? I read a lot but not found a working method, sorry my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your file is not release by `File-I/O`.

SO.. try `flush()` the FileOutPutStream.. like,

```
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

then, use `Uri.fromFile(File file)` for uri to pass with Intent.. But before passing Uri to Intent just check whether file is exist or not..

like,

```
if(newSoundFile.exist())
{
 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(newSoundFile))
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,getString(R.string.share)));
 newSoundFile.delete();
}
```

Comment: As I already read your question with line.. "I can send file to email, dropbox, whatsapp, but if I select Bluetooth, My device shows a message "File null was not sent to ...""

Comment: Works great! But the problem is the newSoundFile.delete();, these line delete the file before it is sended.. :)