# how send audio in raw file via intent

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have many sound tracks in my app and I want to share them via Bluetooth to other device. I have read all the Questions and Answers but I still have problems. When sending via Bluetooth, the device shows a message -

> "File unknown. File not sent.."

I do not know what the problem is? Please help me..

**Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button send=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);  
    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource:// com.example.bluthooth/raw/aaa.mp3");
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
              intent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
              intent.setType("audio/*");

              intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Share"));

        }
    });

     }
   }
```

I have a track named `aaa.mp3` in `raw` folder.

Answer (score 3):

```
File audio = new File("/path/to/audio.mp3");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).setType("audio/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(audio));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share to"));
```

Answer (score -1):

The way you parse your audio file is wrong.

```
File newSoundFile = new File(baseDirectory, fileName);

byte[] readData = new byte[1024*500];
InputStream inputstream = getResources().openRawResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier(filename,"raw", context.getPackageName()));
FileOutputStream outputstream = new FileOutputStream(newSoundFile);
int i = inputstream.read(readData);

while (i != -1) {
    outputstream.write(readData, 0, i);
    i = inputstream.read(readData);
}
outputstream.flush();
outputstream.close();

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(soundfilepath));
//can share in any way - to other applications as well as bluetooth
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,getString(R.string.share)));
//delete the copy
newSoundFile.delete();
```

See this answer here [Android - Share file from sd using bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157965/android-share-file-from-sd-using-bluetooth)